# How to upgrade Eclipse RCP 3.6 project to 4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to upgrade my Eclipse RCP project which was live yesterday, developed using Eclipse RCP 3.6 version(code was like tightly coupled as I didn't use Spring DI), as a future road-map consideration, I'd like to upgrade my project to Eclipse 4. Primary reason for upgrading is to use spring DI & CSS in my RCP application. Can I do spring integration and CSS in my Eclipse RCP 3.6 project  or Should I start from creating an RCP 4 Scratch project. 
Brainstorming for ideas, actually. Any directions & suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question... it is certainly possible to use Spring DI in Eclipse 3.6, but the current CSS styling for Eclipse RCP UI wasn't introduced until Eclipse 4.

I can't address if you should or should not create an RCP 4 Scratch project.  That's a tough decision and it should be made by someone with deep knowledge of your project and its future goals.

As for direction and suggestions...
I have two sources of information for you.

1. Lars Vogella.  His tutorial sites are very well put together, and I consider them a must have for anyone wanting to learn the basics of Eclipse RCP development.  Unfortunately, these tutorials may not be detailed enough to help you.  It depends on your current level of Eclipse RCP knowledge.  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html
2. Eclipse Source.  This is a paid service.  I've never worked with these guys, but they have been sending me some emails offering several different pricing levels for various levels of support.  There web site is well put together and it offers some great information. http://eclipsesource.com/en/eclipse/

Comment: as you stated it is possible to integrate spring DI in eclipse 3.6, can you direct me to an example or link or any resource ?

Comment: I'll point you to Mr Vogella again... I find his tutorials helpful. http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html