# How can I port my eclipse 3.7 application to eclipse 4.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, upgrade

I have an application already developed in Eclipse 3.7, but as Eclipse 4.0 Juno is out I would like to port my RCP application to Juno.

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: That, or just copy your source over.

Comment: What did you try? What is not working? Did you try to run or recompile it with Juno?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Eclipse 4.x the API for Eclipse based application is completely changed. The new API is created as the [Eclipse e4 project](http://www.eclipse.org/e4/). It is not backwards compatible.

You have two choices:

1. use the legacy plugins to be able to still run the old Eclispe 3.x plugins/applications. It is able to support *some* of the new and the old APIs. And your application might still run, albeit less efficient.
2. Rewrite your application (at least the UI part) using the new Eclipse e4 API. The Eclipse e4 API is not yet fully defined and might change in the future. So converting your application and keep it up-to-date with future e4 API changes requires quite some effort.

A very nice tutorial about Eclispe e4 is written by [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html), it will show you the basics of the new API. Furthermore, check the [e4](/questions/tagged/e4) tag on StackOverflow of course!

Answer (score 1):

You can open the same workspace with the newer version of eclipse right away, in case you wanna be on the safe side, create a new workspace and import the project into it from version control if you are using one.

The first option should work smoothly though, except that if you had some plugins with perspectives installed on the old eclipse version, you might get error notifications about that. If you want it clean, go with the second option.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the OP wants to know how to migrate his RCP project to Juno. Nevertheless your answer is the first step (upgrading the development environment).

Comment: Correct. Missed that he mentioned that his project is an RCP project though. Of course the first step would be to upgrade the dev environment. As for RCP which I'm not totally familiar with, there might be some API changes. A question covering this topic for Eclipse 3.6 can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12488694/1897470) it might offer some help!

Comment: "_there might be some API changes_", Eclipse e4 is completely rewritten and incompatible! Luckily, there are legacy plugins to support the old 3.x API...